# Do you have to start every php file with <?php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP so sorry for naive question but every PHP file I've seen starts with `<?php`. Is that mandatory? Are there any well-known workarounds for not having it?

Coming from Node it looks a bit awkward to me.

Comment: yes starting `<?php` is necessary. BTW  ending `?>` is optional

Comment: https://www.wired.com/2010/02/php_tutorial_for_beginners/#Basic_Syntax

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/php/syntax/syntax.php

Comment: Yes it is necessary to start either with <?php or if short_open_tag is on in your config.php file then you can use <?= to start php files , but it is necessary.

Comment: @Anant `<?` with short tags enabled

Comment: No, your first line could be `<!DOCTYPE html>`. You'd lose all functionality that requires no output first though. If you meant for `PHP` to be executed though, then yes.

Comment: @chris85 yes... and no; depending on if they're actually going to echoing something or not.

Comment: this question is starting to attract too many opinion-based answers

Comment: @Anant *"BTW ending ?> is optional"* - is actually better to leave them out if no html is followed and for quite a few reasons, classes for one.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  agreed

Comment: Start with http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php Alex and read through it and embedded hyperlinks; it speaks for itself, and http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php and is really the answer to this question, in its own right (IMHO, anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Welcome to PHP Alex!**

Yes it is ***mandatory one***. Since PHP sometimes when embedded between HTML, the interpreter finds the code when enclosed within such tags. You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

BTW, you can use *short open tag* `<?` (But discouraged since it is disabled by default and can be used only after modifying the php.ini configuration file.)

You can also use *short echo tag* `<?= ?>` when you want to print. This will be like template engine!

---

**FYI**, previously PHP had script tags but it has been removed since the release of PHP 7.0.0. It was like:

```
<script language="php">
...
</script>
```

And so is the ASP style tags too `<% ... %>`.

Comment: instead of adding answer you can provide link

Comment: I have provided it. Check!

Comment: *"But discouraged since it can be used only after modifying in the php.ini configuration file"* - Depending on the version of php. Some have them set by default and `<?=` has been around for a long time.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Edited! I face it with my hosting account!

Comment: @dear downvoters. Can you please explain for the downvote?

Comment: The question of comments + downvotes has been discussed ad nauseum on Meta. Many folks just choose to DV and move on. Many offer advice. Many try to light the path for newbies.

Answer (score 4):

`"<?php"` is neccessary if you want to write the php code, otherwise you can write the html only in php file without `"<?php"`.

if you write `"<?php"` then you are optional to write `?>` to close the php file.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are going to work in PHP files then its necessary to start PHP code with `<?php`

Comment: not really; it can be `<?` if short tags are enabled

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Agreed, but its not recommended :)

Answer (score 1):

**Welcome to php world AlexStack!**

it is necessary to use `<?php`to open the php script "field" but it is not neccessary to close this with `?>`.

you can also use only short tags `<?` or `<?= ?>` but i recommend you to prefer `<?php` with ending `?>` keywords